# Check if Dojo's content pane is available or not

Tags: dojo

I have a requirement where I need to create a `dojox.layout.ContentPane` programmatically.

```
function constructContentPane(methodToBeCalled){
        var testCntPane=new dojox.layout.ContentPane({
                    href: "some url",
                    executeScripts: true,
                    cleanContent: true,
                    onDownloadEnd: methodToBeCalled
                }).placeAt("testContentPaneId");
         testCntPane.startup();
}
```

This places the content pane inside `testContentPaneId` and calls `methodToBeCalled` method once the content pane is created.

I have two questions.

1. How do I check if the content pane is already created or not? I tried to check using the code below

```
if(dijit.byId("testContentPaneId") == undefined) {
    //then don't create again
}
```

But this did not work. Each time it creates the content pane with the id `dojox_layout_ContentPane_0`. The last digit gets incremented each time.

2. Is this the right way to pass the `onComplete` method as argument? This is how I invoke this

```
constructContentPane(thisMethodWillBeCalled);
```

Is there any better way to do this? How do I invoke that method? I tried using `eval(methodToBeCalled)`, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `placeAt()` method then the widget will be placed as a child to the specified dom node. I think in your case you should pass the dom directly to the constructor of the content pane.

Try doing like this instead:

```
var testCntPane=new dojox.layout.ContentPane({
    href:"some url",
    executeScripts:true,
    cleanContent:true,
    onDownloadEnd:methodToBeCalled
    }, "testContentPaneId");
```

This will also make sure that the id of the content pane is `testContentPaneId`

Comment: Thanks Danne. That helped me. How do I invoke a method that is passed as an argument? I tried eval(methodName), but it did not work.

Comment: You only have to put parenthesizes at the end and it should be called, like this: testCntPane.onDownloadEnd();